# `dump': long too big to dump

Tags: ruby, marshalling

Using ruby and marshal I get an error:

> `dump': long too big to dump While writing a large boolean array.

This is the statement seeing the error.

```
File.open(numberlinefile + ".dat", 'wb') {|f| f.write(Marshal.dump(@numberline))}
```

If numberline is too large it stops working.  Is there a limit on the size on object that marshal can deal with?  Would YAML be a better choice?

Comment: I don't really know why it happens, as a simple work around you could convert the number(s) to a string and then store them and conert them to a number back when reading them from the file again...

Comment: Unfortunately, the array is to large for that to be practical.  I estimate it would take a couple of hours to do the conversion.  It takes several hours to generate the array (numberline) from an ascii text  file to start with...